# How copy String to String[] in android

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I have String having data like

```
String myString = "10,20,30,40,50,60";
```

all i want to convert it into String[] to use these value in SQLite for

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, myString ,columnName);
```

But db.delete requires **String[]**
So i want to convert it but it's value is becoming something rubbish and get error at time of delete those Id's from  My_Database.
So if you have any Smart Answer for that please share it.

> My Required Data is

```
String[] myArray = {"10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"};
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's actually How copy String values into String[]....

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to just add them to a list, then call `toArray` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to look for `split()`:

```
String string = "1,2,3,4,5";
String[] parts = string.split(",");

String item1 = parts[0]; // 1
String item2 = parts[1]; // 2
...
```

Comment: Ha, I thought your name was Martin Odersky. I was going to say what an honour! And it's not 100% clear if it's one string containing commas, or several Strings given there's no quotation marks on the question.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski when i use that it convert my string like that from productId 9, 17, 19, 16 to parts [Ljava.lang.String;@41cd08d8

Comment: what is exactly myString content? fix your question

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i put all output above. it only have  **[Ljava.lang.String;@41cd08d8** kind of String instead of 9, 17, 19, 16

Comment: that perfectly what you should get. see edited answer